# Calculate the elapsed time in python

Tags: python

How can I calculates the elapsed time between a start time and an end time of a event using python, in format like 00:00:00 and 23:59:59?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time.time()` is just system time, nothing more. `datetime` is probably a plan, but if you want to DIY, `divmod` works pretty well

```
def pretty_time(t):
    """takes a time, in seconds, and formats it for display"""
    m, s = divmod(t, 60)
    h, m = divmod(m, 60)
    s = round(s) #Rounds seconds to the nearest whole number
    h = str(h).rjust(2,'0') #covert to strings,
    m = str(m).rjust(2,'0') #adding 0 if necessary to make 
    s = str(s).rjust(2,'0') #each one two digits long
    return "{}:{}:{}".format(h,m,s)
```

and then just call with

```
pretty_time(end_time-start_time)
```

(examples:

```
In [5]: pretty_time(3600)
Out[5]: '01:00:00'

In [6]: pretty_time(3500)
Out[6]: '00:58:20'
```

)

(note that I didn't bother to check for times over 24 hours, that'll just give you things like "25:45:21")

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you can do it with `time` module , but you can use the `datetime` module for that, get the result `datetime.datetime.now()` when the event starts and save it in a variable.

Then when the event ends again get `datetime.datetime.now()` and subtract the first time from it. You will get a `datetime.timedelta()` object, which you can convert to `str()` to get the data in your required format.

Example/Demo -

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> d1 = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> str(d1 - d)
'0:00:06.989000'
>>> str(datetime.timedelta(0,84332,12332))
'23:25:32.012332'
```

If you do not want the microsecond part, you can just use `rsplit()` on `'.'` and take the first part, Example -

```
>>> str(d1 - d).rsplit('.',1)[0]
'0:00:06'
>>> str(datetime.timedelta(0,84332,12332)).rsplit('.',1)[0]
'23:25:32'
```

Comment: That's not what i want... sorry ToT   But thank u for the answer

Comment: Well according to the question this is exactly what you want (just the difference of the module) , can you please explain what else if the requirement?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I wrote my question wrong, I'm so stupid ToT

Comment: Ok then what is the question? I also added the part to remove the `microsecond` part (after the dot) .